# Simultaneous access to database; keeping data consistent across all connections

Tags: database, database-design

I made a database system right here:

[image] (comments on the normalization are highly appreciated as well - I have a feeling you'll hate me on what I did with tblIsolateSensitivity; tblHAIFile only has a bunch of Boolean fields and foreign keys).

Let's say we have x number of terminals accessing the database. X1 edits Patient 01, X2 edits Patient 02, X3 deletes Patient 01 at the same time. How can I ensure that the data between the three terminals are all up-to-date and consistent?

At the moment, I am querying the data only when the query is needed to be done (ie: when the user searches for a record, or if the program needs to verify something against a database record), meaning the data is only as updated as the most recent query that the user makes. This makes it difficult to ensure that the data is up-to-date on all terminals. Of course, for deleted entries, I have error handling to handle that, but for the rest, well...

So, my question is: how do you guys typically handle this kind of situation? Is there a name for this concept so that I can look it up and read long?

Answer (score 3):

From a database design perspective, you should read up on **optimistic concurrency** and **pessimistic concurrency**.  These are two options for making sure that you either don't have two users modifying the same record at the same time, or at least if you do allow that, the conflict is detected so it can be resolved.

The basic idea behind *optimistic concurrency* is that you allow multiple users to view and modify the data at the same time, on the assumption that this will be relatively rare.  However, before any user writes changes to the data, a check is made to ensure that the underlying data hasn't changed since it was originally read.  In some cases you do this manually with a read before update, checking each column value against a cached value.  However, that is cumbersome.  Some DBMS systems have features that make this simpler.  For example, SQL Server has the **ROWVERSION** (formerly known as TIMESTAMP) data type, which lets you check easily using a single value whether someone else has changed a record since the last time you read it.

The basic idea behind *pessimistic concurrency* is that you put a lock on a record in the expectation that you're going to change it.  While you hold the lock, the DBMS will prevent anyone else from getting their own lock.

The advantage of optimistic concurrency is that it's pretty light weight, doesn't interfere too much with your application, and let's you manually (or automatically) resolve any conflicts on those rare occasions when they happen.  You also don't have to worry about someone reading a record, locking it and then going home for the weekend.

The advantage of pessimistic concurrency is that it prevents collisions, but it can stop one user from working while they wait for another to finish what they're doing.

From the perspective of notifying users when records change in the background (i.e. they're changed by another user) that isn't a database design feature.  It may be a feature of your application logic or of your application's data access layer.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation! I'd have to admit, I was thinking of doing pessimistic concurrency (not just because I'm usually a pess- I mean, realist) to the records on the database. The problem I think that could occur with that is if the application/DB connection crashes and the record is left locked until such time that a DBA unlocks the said record.

Comment: @RemiDarren Your last sentence of your comment is a non-issue. Any serious database system such as Postgres, MS SQL Server, Oracle, and such automatically release locks held by any connection that gracefully closes or tragically fails. Likewise, any transaction in progress by that closed/failed connection is rolled-back. These are some of the basic duties of a database server.

Comment: @RemiDarren See: [pessimistic locking and client death](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/37225/19079)